# parse gmail and append to google sheets returns error undefined (apps script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I'm trying to execute a script I found on github that parses emails and appends to a google sheet from a gmail account.

https://github.com/jimi985/RSVP-Google-App-Script

The error I get running AddRSVPToSpreadsheet is

**TypeError: Cannot call method "toArray" of undefined. (line 154, file "Code")**

I'm running these functions step by step and the example text has been emailed, The gsheets string added and script allowed to access email account.

Email label also is; Wedding RSVPs

Could it be the order that I'm running the functions?

RSVP
initializespreadsheet
processrsvps
addrsvpstospreadsheet

Is there a special order?
This order is layed out in apps script interface when I select run function.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? or explain why I'm getting this error?

```
/*
 *
 * Script that pulls data in from Gmail with a specific label.
 * All RSVP emails for my wedding are automatically filtered to this label.
 * Then the emails are parsed and appended to the spreadhseet if they aren't already in the sheet.
 *
 * Example Email:

From: John Doe & Jane Doe <jdoe123@gmail.com>
Subject: John Doe & Jane Doe Fitzgerald has RSVP
Name: John Doe & Jane Doe
Email: jdoe123@gmail.com
Number of Guest(s): 1
Events:
Can Attend: No
 *
 */


/*
 * Global Variables
 */
var LOGGING_ENABLED = true;

//Set a start date to filter out older emails
// var date = new Date('April 20, 2019 18:30:00');
// var START_TIME = date.getTime();
var START_DATE = new Date('April 20, 2019 18:30:00');
var MAX_THREADS_TO_PROCESS = 0;

//Set which label we are using to filter which emails are being retrieved
var RSVP_LABEL = 'Wedding RSVPs';
var SPREADSHEET_ID = 'example2403tehewreotherer';

var spreadsheet_field_names = [];
var sheet;

if(LOGGING_ENABLED){
    //Clear out previous logs
    Logger.clear();
    log("Starting script: Parse Wedding RSVPs");
}

/*
 * RSVP class that stores the details of the rsvp
 * Also has a toArray method that is useful for passing the data
 * into a Gmail Spreadsheet.
 */
function RSVP(){

    this.property_order = ['date', 'name', 'email', 'number_of_guests', 'events', 'can_attend'];

    this.toArray = function(){
        var arr = [];
        for(i = 0; i < this.property_order.length; i++){
            if(this.hasOwnProperty(this.property_order[i])){
                arr.push(this[this.property_order[i]]);
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }

}

/*
 * Loads the spreadsheet based on the predefined spreadsheet,
 * Then populates the list of header fields within the spreadsheet.
 * @returns - {boolean} - true if successful, false on failure.
 */
function initializeSpreadsheet(){

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID);

    if(!spreadsheet){
        return false;
    }

    sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

    if(!sheet){
        return false;
    }

    spreadsheet_field_names = getSpreadsheetFieldNames(sheet);

    if(!spreadsheet_field_names || spreadsheet_field_names.length <= 0){
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}

/*
 * Function that retrieves a list of gmail email threads
 * with a provided label and parses them.
 * @param - {string} rsvp_label - The label applied to emails that should be parsed.
 */
function processRSVPs(rsvp_label) {

    var rsvp_threads = getGmailThreadsWithLabelName(rsvp_label);

    if(rsvp_threads.length <= 0){
        log("No Wedding RSVP Threads found");
        return false;
    }

    //We found some emails to parse, open the spreadsheet
    if(!initializeSpreadsheet()){
        log("Failed to initialize spreadsheet.");
        return false;
    }

    messages = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < rsvp_threads.length; i++) {

        messages = messages.concat(rsvp_threads[i].getMessages());

        //While debugging, only try to process the first few email threads
        if(MAX_THREADS_TO_PROCESS > 0 && (i + 1) >= MAX_THREADS_TO_PROCESS){
            break;
        }

    }

    //Filter out messages we don't want to parse (based on date or other criteria)
    messages = filterMessages(messages);

    for(i = 0; i < messages.length; i++){

        var rsvp = parseRSVPEmail(messages[i].getBody());
        rsvp.date = formatDate(messages[i].getDate());

        //Add rsvp entry to spreadsheet
        if(addRSVPToSpreadsheet(rsvp)) {
            log("RSVP Successfully added to spreadsheet: " + JSON.stringify(rsvp));
        }else{
            log("RSVP could not be added to spreadsheet: " + JSON.stringify(rsvp));
        }

    }

}

/*
 * Loops through an array of email threads and parses each thread.
 * @param - {Object} rsvp - the rsvp object to add to the spreadsheet.
 * @returns - {boolean} - true if added to the spreadsheet,
 *  false if already exists or there was an error.
 */
function addRSVPToSpreadsheet(rsvp){

    //Convert the rsvp object into an array
    rsvp_array = rsvp.toArray();    

    if(RSVPEntryExists(rsvp, sheet)){
        log('Entry already found in spreadsheet: ' + JSON.stringify(rsvp));
        return false;
    }

    sheet = sheet.appendRow(rsvp_array);

    return true;

}

/*
 * Returns the list of field names from the first row of a spreadsheet.
 * @param {Sheet} sheet - Gmail Sheet object.
 * @param {string[]} - array of field names.
 */
function getSpreadsheetFieldNames(sheet){

    //Find the column index of the last row
    var last_column = sheet.getLastColumn();

    //Sheet.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
    //Get all of the values from the first row
    var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, last_column);
    var values = range.getValues();

    var header = [];
    for (var row in values) {
        for (var col in values[row]) {
            header_column_name = values[row][col].toLowerCase();
            header_column_name = replaceAll(' ', '_', header_column_name);
            header_column_name = replaceAll('[^a-z0-9_]', '', header_column_name);
            header.push(header_column_name);
        }
    }

    return header;

}

/*
 * Checks if the RSVP entry already exists in the Spreadsheet.
 * @param {RSVP} rsvp - RSVP object to be checked.
 * @param {Sheet} sheet - Gmail Sheet to be checked.
 * @returns {boolean} - true if the entry exists or if there was an error, otherwise false.
 */
function RSVPEntryExists(rsvp, sheet){

    //Find the column that we need to be searching
    search_column = spreadsheet_field_names.indexOf('name');

    if(search_column == -1){
        //Flag the entry as existing since there was an error.

        return true;
    }

    var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();

    // getRange(row, column, numRows)
    //Get all of the values from the search column for all rows
    //(Add 1 to the search_column as the Spreadsheet is 1-indexed instead of 0-indexed)
    //Start on row 2 as we don't want the header row
    var range = sheet.getRange(2, search_column + 1, last_row);

    var values = range.getValues();

    for (var row in values) {
        for (var col in values[row]) {
            if(values[row][col] == rsvp.name){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;

}

/*
 * Filters an array of messages and returns a modified version of the original array
 * @param - {GmailMessage[]} messages - list of messages to be filtered.
 * @returns - {GmailMessage[]} - filtered list of messages.
 */
function filterMessages(messages) {

    if(messages.length <= 0){
        return false;
    }

     // The messages need to be traversed in reverse order
     // This is because we need to call the splice method to remove an element from
     // the messages array which reindexes the array
    for (var i = messages.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        //Filter out messages if they are older than our start date.
        if(isMessageOlderThanDate(messages[i], START_DATE)) {
            messages.splice(i, 1);
            continue;
        }

    }

    return messages;

}

/*
 * Returns true if a message occurred after a specified date, otherwise false.
 * This allows emails to be skipped that have already been processed.
 * @param {GmailMessage} message - The GmailMessage object to be checked.
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isMessageOlderThanDate(message, start_date) {
    return (message.getDate().getTime() > start_date.getTime()) ? false : true;
}

/*
 * Parses an email of a specific format to retrieve its component parts
 * The email must be formatted with as: <string>: <string>, representing a key/value pair.
 * @param - {string} body - the contents of an rsvp email.
 * @returns - {Object} - rsvp details object.
 */
function parseRSVPEmail(body) {

    body = replaceAll('<br />', '', body);

    var message_lines = body.split("\n");

    //Initialize our RSVP Object
    rsvp = new RSVP();

    var skip_fields = ['from', 'subject']

    for(i = 0; i < message_lines.length; i++) {

        var line_parts = message_lines[i].split(':');

        //Make the line type lower case, replace spaces with underscores, and remove any other unexpected character
        // var line_type = line_parts[0].toLowerCase().replaceAll(' ', '_').replaceAll('/[^a-z0-9_]/', '');
        var line_type = line_parts[0].toLowerCase();
        line_type = replaceAll(' ', '_', line_type);
        line_type = replaceAll('[^a-z0-9_]', '', line_type);

        //Skip over fields we don't need
        if(skip_fields.indexOf(line_type) != -1){
            continue;
        }

        //In case there's a ":" in the message, reassemble the rest of the line
        var line_value = "";

        for(var j = 1; j < line_parts.length; j++) {
            line_value += line_parts[j];
        }

        line_value = line_value.trim();

        rsvp[line_type] = line_value;

        if(line_type == 'can_attend'){
            //can_attend is the last line of the email that needs to be parsed
            //Break out of all loops or return
            break;
        }

    }

    return rsvp;

}

/*
 * Returns an array of GmailThreads that match a provided label.
 * @param {string} label_name - Gmail Label name being searched for.
 */
function getGmailThreadsWithLabelName(label_name) {

    var threads = [];
    var new_threads = [];
    var start = 0;
    var loop_count = 30;

    //First see if we can find the label
    var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label_name);

    //We could not retrieve a label, fail out.
    if(!label){
        return threads;
    }

    do {
        new_threads = label.getThreads(start,loop_count);
        threads = threads.concat(new_threads);
        start += loop_count;
    }
    while(new_threads.length > 0);

    return threads;

}

/*
 * Additional String method expanding on the existing replace method,
 * allowing all matches of a regular expression to be replaced.
 * @param {string} find - Regular expression string
 * @param {string} replace - String to replace the matches that are found.
 */
// String.prototype.replaceAll = function(find, replace) {
//  return this.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(find), 'g'), replace);
// }

function replaceAll(find, replace, subject){
    return subject.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}

/*
 * Helper function that escapes a regular expression provided as a string
 * @param {string} regex - Regular expression string.
 * This escape does not work if you are trying to use metacharacters in your regular expression.
 */
function escapeRegExp(regex) {
    return regex.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}

/*
 * Helper function to format a javascript datetime value to be stored in a spreadsheet
 * @param {Date} date - Javascript date object to be formatted
 * @returns {string} - date formatted as "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS"
 */
function formatDate(date) {
    var formatted_date = (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();
    var formatted_time = date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes() + ':' + date.getSeconds();
    return formatted_date + ' ' + formatted_time;
}

/*
 * Custom logging function that checks if logging has been enabled
 * @param {String} message - message to be logged.
 */
function log(message){
    if(LOGGING_ENABLED){
        Logger.log(message);
    }
}

processRSVPs(RSVP_LABEL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run the function `addRSVPToSpreadsheet` from the editor's run menu because it takes a parameter `rsvp`.  The error you are getting is because the run menu tries to run `addRSVPToSpreadsheet()`, i.e. without the `rsvp` parameter.  `rsvp` is assigned the value `undefined` and thus `undefined.toArray()` results in the error you're seeing.

The order in the run menu is simply the order the functions appear in the current script file.  It does not imply you should run them in that order.

The entry point of the script appears to be the last line

```
processRSVPs(RSVP_LABEL);
```

and if you wanted to call that line in the run menu, you will need to add a driver function e.g.

```
function startProcess() {
  processRSVPs(RSVP_LABEL);
}
```

Comment: I tried your function to execute the entrypoint but nothing gets updated or added in the spreadsheet. No errors either or nothing showing when debugging function

Comment: How did you debug the function? Have you tried adding a breakpoint and using the editor's built in debugger?